# How to change color of Icon after function executes within onTap ( Flutter ListItem)

Tags: flutter

Want to change the color of Icon when tapped. By default if item if already favorite, Icon is red while others are of default color.

If user taps on Icon to make it favorite or Unfavorite, I want to change the color after update.

```
new ListTile(
    trailing: InkWell(
      child: Icon(Icons.share),
    ),
    leading: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          snapshot.data[index].isFavorite == 0
              ? makeFavorite(snapshot.data[index].id)
              : makeUnfavorite(
              snapshot.data[index].id);
        },
        child: snapshot.data[index].isFavorite == 1
            ? Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.red,
        )
            : Icon(Icons.favorite)),
    title: new Text(snapshot.data[index].body,
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0)),
),
```

Comment: your item should be a StatefulWidget then you can create a var to handle the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved the problem this way (Updated Code)**

**Code of List Tile**

```
new ListTile(
                        trailing: InkWell(
                          child: Icon(Icons.share),
                        ),
                        leading: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              snapshot.data[index].isFavorite == 0
                                  ? makeFavorite(
                                      snapshot.data[index].id, index)
                                  : makeUnfavorite(
                                      snapshot.data[index].id, index);
                            },
                            child: (indexes[index] == 1)
                                ? Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  )
                                : Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                        title: new Text(snapshot.data[index].body,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0)),
                      ),
```

**Functions for changing state**

```
 makeFavorite(int id, int index) {
    // operations to be performed
    // end of operations to be performed
    setState(() {
      indexes[index] = 1;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an Statefull widget for change it's state

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new ListItem();
      }),
    );
  }

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ItemView();
  }
  class _ItemView extends State<ListItem>{
    bool isFavorite = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new ListTile(
        trailing: InkWell(
          child: Icon(Icons.share),
        ),
        leading: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              isFavorite = !isFavorite;
              setState(() {
              });
            },
            child: isFavorite ? Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: Colors.red,
            ): Icon(Icons.favorite)),
        title: new Text('Your Text',
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0)),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: But I am getting data in snapshot and within onTap function, I have to perform some operation after which I should update color of Icon. However, I have found a solution by taking another list which only save 1s or 0s according to indexes of this data list.
Now I change the state of only that index of the list withing onTap, and color of icon now depends on the values of that list.

Answer (score 0):

use setState inside onTap function and assign color there.